# How to escape single quotes as part of an alias composite command?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I would like to create an alias that goes to my project and switches automatically to the latest candidate release branch which by convention has the pattern e.g. `crel_1.0.1`. To do that I have the following alias defined in my `.bashrc` but due to the lack of escaping the single quotes part of the awk command I get errors either starting or during the running of the alias. I have tried using double quotes outside but I get errors too. I have tried escaping with the `'\''` approach but I get errors too.

```
alias candidate='cd $PROJECT_HOME && git checkout . && git clean -fd && export CREL_BRANCH=`git branch --list crel* | awk '{ print $NF }'` && git checkout $CREL_BRANCH && git pull'
```

The problematic sub-command is the following, which being inside tilde then I am not sure how to escape:

```
export CREL_BRANCH=`git branch --list crel* | awk '{ print $NF }'`
```

I get the following error when starting a new shell:

```
bash: alias: print: not found
bash: alias: }` && git checkout $CREL_BRANCH && git pull: not found
```

and this other error when running the alias:

```
> bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I need the awk bit to get the last word of the output which corresponds to the branch name I am interested in.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: How about export CREL_BRANCH="$(git branch --list crel* | awk '{ print $NF }')"?

Comment: Start by using a function instead of an alias.

Comment: @RamanSailopal I get errors launching a new shell `bash: alias: print: not found
bash: alias: })" && git checkout $CREL_BRANCH && git pull: not found`

Comment: @Shawn can you post an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @SkyWalker : If you get certain errors from a specific command, please include the error message inside your question, not in a comment.

Comment: BTW, you can create a function in ```~/.bashrc``` that will do the same

Comment: Try this `"cd \$PROJECT_HOME && git checkout . && git clean -fd && export CREL_BRANCH=\$(git branch --list crel* | awk '{ print \$NF }') && git checkout \$CREL_BRANCH && git pull"`

Comment: Try to double quote your awk program instead of using single quotes: `awk "{ print $NF }"`. And I agree with other comments: for complex things like this one a function would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have entered the realm where it no longer makes sense to use an alias - your code is just too big to be a one-liner.

The recommendation to use a function is a good one. Just replace your alias with:

```
candidate () {
    cd $PROJECT_HOME || return
    git checkout . 
    git clean -fd 
    export CREL_BRANCH=`git branch --list crel* | awk '{ print $NF }'`
    git checkout $CREL_BRANCH
    git pull
}
```

However, unless the `CREL_BRANCH` variable export is important to you I would recommend creating a script instead.

If you don't already have one, create a `bin` directory in your `$HOME` to store all your personal scripts:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Add this directory to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Then create a file called `candidate` and make it executable:

```
touch ~/bin/candidate
chmod +x ~/bin/candidate
```

Edit the `candidate` file:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd $PROJECT_HOME || exit
git checkout . 
git clean -fd 
CREL_BRANCH=`git branch --list crel* | awk '{ print $NF }'`
git checkout $CREL_BRANCH
git pull
```

Scripts are much more maintainable and easier to modify. The only issue with scripts is that it runs in a subshell so you cannot export any variables from scripts.

If you need to export variables use a function. Still, I recommend to save that function in another file such as `candidate.sh` then in your bashrc add:

```
# Import candidate function (note the space after the dot!)
. /path/to/candidate.sh
```

Comment: If you use a script, you should start it with a shebang line, like `#!/bin/bash`, so the system knows which shell to run it in. Also, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will have some other good suggestions.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yup. Was rushing to type up an answer. Will fix it

Answer (score 0):

---

How about using `$( print $NF )` instead of `'{ print $NF }'` ?

So you should try this :

```
alias candidate='cd $PROJECT_HOME && git checkout . && git clean -fd && export CREL_BRANCH=`git branch --list crel* | awk $( print $NF )` && git checkout $CREL_BRANCH && git pull'
```

Comment: Using `$( print $NF )` this way will run `print $NF` as a shell command instead of as an `awk` script, so it won't work at all.